# why are these VM:UITableViewCellSelectedBackground(CALayer) come out for every UITableViewCell in Allocations?

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks, allocation

I am using allocations to test my decompression code for my app. I use a Master `UITableViewController` to display 11 filenames. the test app screenshot is as followings:
[image]

when you select one, it will push a `UIViewController` to display the file, then come back to Master `UITableViewController`.

Now if you repeat to select one cell, there is no memory spike in the chart. But if you select from 1 to 2, it will increase at least 224KB memory between the generations. I test from 1 to 11. all these changes will will increase almost the same memory. the screenshot is as followings:
[image]

I check the detail find there is a `VM:UITableViewCellSelectedBackground(CALayer)` (some named `VM:CoreAnimation`, but all are the same 224KB) in the growth. And if i select the selected cells, there is no such big memory spike. it seems they will only be created at the first time one cell is selected.

Now my question is why are they come out? is this a kind of memory leak? and if yes, how can i fix it? Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
i have confirmed there is nothing related to my decompression code, if i comment out the decompression code, the `VM:UITableViewCellSelectedBackground(CALayer)` is still there when selected a new cell.

Comment: I have a tall UITableView in a popover on iPad, and I get similar results from repeatedly scrolling up and down. I also see `VM: UILabel (CALayer)` continually allocated in addition to `VM:UITableViewCellSelectedBackground(CALayer)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in simulator, result is similar to you. But memory will fall down after a while.

I don't think this is memory leak. When we select one cell, system may add a translucent layer above the it.

The layer is created when needed so it increase the memory.

I am sure once one cell is selected, the system will create some objects (something is related to the layer or the layer itself) that won't be released though the cell is deselected later, those objects maybe some cache to improve the performance when the cell is selected next time.